# I want to assign variables to first 3 'titles' returned in my response

Tags: python, dictionary

But in some cases, 'results' are less than 3 and I get 'out of range' error. so how do I assign just as many variables as there are results('total_results') in my response? It is my first question here so I am sorry if it is not properly phrased.

```py
import requests, json

response  = requests.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&language=en-US&query=Batman%20Begins&page=1&include_adult=false')

result_dict = response.json()


#copy-pasting what fetched response looks like

result_dict = {'page': 1, 'total_results': 2, 'total_pages': 1, 'results': [{'popularity': 34.077, 'vote_count': 14576, 'video': False, 'poster_path': '/8RW2runSEc34IwKN2D1aPcJd2UL.jpg', 'id': 272, 'adult': False, 'backdrop_path': '/lh5lbisD4oDbEKgUxoRaZU8HVrk.jpg', 'original_language': 'en', 'original_title': 'Batman Begins', 'genre_ids': [28, 80, 18], 'title': 'Batman Begins', 'vote_average': 7.7, 'overview': 'Driven by tragedy, billionaire Bruce Wayne dedicates his life to uncovering and defeating the corruption that plagues his home, Gotham City.  Unable to work within the system, he instead creates a new identity, a symbol of fear for the criminal underworld - The Batman.', 'release_date': '2005-06-10'}, {'popularity': 2.786, 'id': 498471, 'video': True, 'vote_count': 3, 'vote_average': 8.7, 'title': 'Batman: The Animated Series - The Legend Begins', 'release_date': '1992-04-23', 'original_language': 'en', 'original_title': 'Batman: The Animated Series - The Legend Begins', 'genre_ids': [16, 28], 'backdrop_path': None, 'adult': False, 'overview': 'Taking a cue from the caped crusader\'s comic book rebirth in Frank Miller\'s The Dark Knight Returns and Batman: Year One, this 1992 animated series saved the TV Batman from a fate worse than camp and drew an unexpected audience for an afternoon cartoon: adults. The initial five episodes gathered here feature such supervillains as Man-bat, the Scarecrow, and Poison Ivy, but the deliciously demented Joker (voiced by Mark Hamill) steals the show in his two appearances, especially in the twisted "Christmas with the Joke." Escaping Arkham Asylum in a rocket-powered Christmas tree, the clown prince of crime preempts a TV showing of It\'s a Wonderful Life with his own homicidal holiday treat. It\'s a solid start to a sleek, stylized, smartly written series that only improved with time. Ages 7 and up.', 'poster_path': '/A3VfRAu8UqN13Jdr8JYh3Kb48DY.jpg'}]}


title1 = ((result_dict.get('results')[0])['title'])
title2 = ((result_dict.get('results')[1])['title'])
title3 = ((result_dict.get('results')[2])['title'])
```

Comment: Having dynamically created variables is a bad idea. How will you know later on whether `title3` exists? It seems you should slice the result and put them in a list. `titles = result_dict.get('results')[:3]`

Comment: you can check `len(result_dict.get('results'))` then access title.

Answer (score 0):

```py
titles = list()
for idx in range(result_dict['total_results']):
    titles.append(result_dict['results'][idx])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
result_dict = {'page': 1, 'total_results': 2, 'total_pages': 1, 'results': [{'popularity': 34.077, 'vote_count': 14576, 'video': False, 'poster_path': '/8RW2runSEc34IwKN2D1aPcJd2UL.jpg', 'id': 272, 'adult': False, 'backdrop_path': '/lh5lbisD4oDbEKgUxoRaZU8HVrk.jpg', 'original_language': 'en', 'original_title': 'Batman Begins', 'genre_ids': [28, 80, 18], 'title': 'Batman Begins', 'vote_average': 7.7, 'overview': 'Driven by tragedy, billionaire Bruce Wayne dedicates his life to uncovering and defeating the corruption that plagues his home, Gotham City.  Unable to work within the system, he instead creates a new identity, a symbol of fear for the criminal underworld - The Batman.', 'release_date': '2005-06-10'}, {'popularity': 2.786, 'id': 498471, 'video': True, 'vote_count': 3, 'vote_average': 8.7, 'title': 'Batman: The Animated Series - The Legend Begins', 'release_date': '1992-04-23', 'original_language': 'en', 'original_title': 'Batman: The Animated Series - The Legend Begins', 'genre_ids': [16, 28], 'backdrop_path': None, 'adult': False, 'overview': 'Taking a cue from the caped crusader\'s comic book rebirth in Frank Miller\'s The Dark Knight Returns and Batman: Year One, this 1992 animated series saved the TV Batman from a fate worse than camp and drew an unexpected audience for an afternoon cartoon: adults. The initial five episodes gathered here feature such supervillains as Man-bat, the Scarecrow, and Poison Ivy, but the deliciously demented Joker (voiced by Mark Hamill) steals the show in his two appearances, especially in the twisted "Christmas with the Joke." Escaping Arkham Asylum in a rocket-powered Christmas tree, the clown prince of crime preempts a TV showing of It\'s a Wonderful Life with his own homicidal holiday treat. It\'s a solid start to a sleek, stylized, smartly written series that only improved with time. Ages 7 and up.', 'poster_path': '/A3VfRAu8UqN13Jdr8JYh3Kb48DY.jpg'}]}
titles = []

for result_id in range(result_dict["total_results"]):
    titles.append(result_dict["results"][result_id]["title"])
print(titles)
```

Output:

```
['Batman Begins', 'Batman: The Animated Series - The Legend Begins']
```